# Is it possible to run Sonar on 64-bit system, CentOS?

Tags: java, centos, sonarqube

I just installed Sonar 3.2 on CentOS (uname -a = Linux mydomain.com 3.2.20-1.29.6.amzn1.x86_64).  I'm using a 64-bit version version of Java …

```
$ java -version 
java version "1.6.0_24" 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (amazon-52.1.11.3.45.amzn1-x86_64)
```

I want to install Sonar as part of Jenkins (build integration server), but when attempting to run it, it repeatedly dies with a "A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment" error.  I can't tell the specific cause.  Does Sonar run with a 64-bit JVM?  How can I troubleshoot this further?

Below is the command I run and the eventual error I get ...

```
[myuser@mydomain workspace]$ sudo /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin/mvn -f "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Sales Client/workspace/pom.xml" -e -B sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on. 
[INFO] Scanning for projects... 
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.mainco.subco:myclient:war:1.0 
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for quickbase:quickbase:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/quickbase.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 75, column 16 
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build. 
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects. 
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Building myclient 1.0 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) @ myclient --- 
[INFO] Sonar version: 3.2 
[INFO] [14:43:11.995] Create JDBC datasource to url jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar 
[INFO] [14:43:14.081] Initializing Hibernate 
[INFO] [14:43:18.186] -------------  Analyzing myclient 
[INFO] [14:43:19.142] Selected quality profile : [name=Sonar way,language=java] 
[INFO] [14:43:19.409] Configure maven plugins... 
[INFO] [14:43:19.598] Compare to previous analysis (2012-09-14) 
[INFO] [14:43:19.680] Compare over 5 days (2012-09-09, analysis of 2012-09-14 11:35:22.0) 
[INFO] [14:43:19.719] Compare over 30 days (2012-08-15, analysis of 2012-09-14 11:35:22.0) 
[INFO] [14:43:19.857] Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Sales Client/workspace/target/jacoco.exec 
[INFO] [14:43:20.042] JaCoCo agent (version 0.5.8.201207111220) extracted: /tmp/jacocoagent5605291050104287245.jar 
[INFO] [14:43:20.043] JVM options: -javaagent:/tmp/jacocoagent5605291050104287245.jar=destfile=target/jacoco.exec,excludes=*_javassist_* 
[INFO] [14:43:20.072] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer... 
[INFO] [14:43:20.078] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer done: 6 ms 
[INFO] [14:43:20.078] Execute maven plugin maven-surefire-plugin... 
[INFO] [14:43:20.078] Execute org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test... 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Building myclient 1.0 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-cli) @ myclient --- 
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Sales Client/workspace/target/surefire-reports 

------------------------------------------------------- 
 T E S T S 
------------------------------------------------------- 
Running org.mainco.subco.Sales.ProcessOrdersWorkerTest 
0    [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging  - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4jLoggerProvider 
182  [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry  - Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@789934d4 
183  [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry  - Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@789934d4 
... 
8428 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory  - Setting dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect] 
8428 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory  - Setting dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect] 
# 
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: 
# 
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f65ec8627e7, pid=8357, tid=140075590440704 
# 
# JRE version: 6.0_31-b04 
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.6-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops) 
# Problematic frame: 
# V  [libjvm.so+0x7a27e7]  ContiguousSpace::prepare_for_compaction(CompactPoint*)+0x227 
# 
# An error report file with more information is saved as: 
# /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Sales Client/workspace/hs_err_pid8357.log 
# 
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit: 
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp    
# 
/bin/sh: line 1:  8357 Aborted                 /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31/jre/bin/java '-javaagent:/tmp/jacocoagent5605291050104287245.jar=destfile=target/jacoco.exec,excludes=*_javassist_*' -jar '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Sales Client/workspace/target/surefire/surefirebooter9057179906457468987.jar' '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Sales Client/workspace/target/surefire/surefire9129544007090882593tmp' '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Sales Client/workspace/target/surefire/surefire1194130731343095454tmp' 

Results : 

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine in Centos/Redhat 64bits. I have a server at home running both sonar and Jenkins without any issue. It might be the mix of versions of centos/java that you're using. Could you try updating your JDK to the latest version?

Comment: please beware that the JDK used to run maven (/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31) is NOT the same is shown with `which` command (openjdk 1.6.0_24)

Comment: My $JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to "1.6.0_24", so where is Sonar looking for the Java version it's running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is caused by [SONAR-3701](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3701).

Comment: This is true.  Upgrading to Sonar 3.2.1 fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, running both Sonar and Jenkins on this machine:

> $ uname -a
>   Linux {HOSTNAME} 2.6.18-274.12.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Nov 29 13:37:46 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> $ java -version
>   java version "1.6.0_20"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.10) (rhel-1.23.1.9.10.el5_7-x86_64)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)

We run ant builds, not maven.  We run our tests and coverage as ant targets, and load sonar as a separate target, not trying to run tests via sonar.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this.  What do you have set for JAVA_OPTS, if anything?

Comment: Nothing globally, different projects have java options set in either Makefile or build.xml.  We're a mixed language shop, and have some applications that are mixed languages, usually java added to a c++ environment.  So a Makefile may build both c++ and fire off ant to build java.  The options vary depending on the needs of what is being built.